# jQuery Autocompletes: set select action for a specific item

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have an auto-complete where the last item in the list is an "Add" button. I want this to have a custom "selected" action, and I want to define it outside of .autocomplete because it is a special case.

Is there some way to change the selected action for a list item in an autocomplete?

```
$('.my-autocomplete').autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) {
      // do stuff
   }
   ... // more settings
});
```

The auto complete is defined as above, but I want all list items having the 'add' class to do something different. I dont want to check the class in the above code because it is a special case and only for this one page (whereas the above code applies to all autocompletes on the entire site).

Comment: Is your auto-complete an input element?  Do you have an example?

Comment: Yes it is an input. updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the source of autocomplete, there didn't seem to be an existing mechanism for doing that.

I understand your desire to not litter common code with special cases, but how about a generic mechanism for handling those special cases? (That is, do what you wished autocomplete had done out-of-the-box yourself)

I'm not sure how you're doing this exactly, since you speak of "list items having the 'add' class", implying you're working with html elements instead of the objects from the data source, so I'm sorry if the example doesn't apply to your situation.

Example of what I mean:

```
function special_handler(event, data) {
    // do special stuff
}

var source = [{value: 'Normal item'}, {value: 'Special item', customselect: special_handler}];

$('.my-autocomplete').autocomplete({
    select: function(event, data) {
        if(data.item.customselect) {
            data.item.customselect(event, data);
        } else {
            // do normal stuff
        }
    },
    source: source
    ... // more settings
});
```

Comment: This looks like it could work. How do I add that custom select function? Can I just select the items and add it like this: $('add').customselect = function() {...} ?

Comment: What element are you adding the "add" class on, and how? Can you give a more detailed example than what's already on your question? For example, what kind of html markup you are using, and what kind of data comes out of your data source.

Comment: The data is loaded asynchronously from the server. The values are rendered as a <ul> with a <li class='ui-menu-item' role='menu-item'> for each list item. The add item also has the class 'add'. I might be able to attach the customselect function _renderItem function... would that work?

Comment: That should work. One option is adding the customselect at the same place you're adding the "add" class. I'm still not sure where and according to what criteria that happens, but if it's decided based directly on the data the data source gives, you could wrap the data source so that it returns data with customselect already added.